# Why isn't my configuraton overwritten for the test environment in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

I have a symfony2 application that requires a different config settings for certain environments, e.g. `test`.

I overwrite my config.yml for the test envioronment like so:

`AppKernel.php`:

```
public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    foreach ($this->getBundles() as $bundle) {
        if (false === strpos($bundle->getName(), 'Dreamlines')) {
            continue;
        }
        $configFile = $bundle->getPath() . '/Resources/config/config.yml';
        if (!file_exists($configFile)) {
            continue;
        }
        $loader->load($configFile);
    }

    $loader->load(__DIR__ . '/config/config_' . $this->getEnvironment() . '.yml');
}
```

In my `config.yml` I define:

```
default_airports:
    cun:
        de:
            - FRA
```

and in my config_test.yml I define the following to overwrite the value:

```
default_airports:
    cun:
        de:
            - HAM
```

My ConfigTreeBuilder looks for the config looks like

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
$rootNode = $treeBuilder
->root('le_bundle');

    $rootNode
    ...
    ->arrayNode('default_airports')
       ->isRequired()
       ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
        ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
        ->prototype('array')
            ->prototype('array')
                ->prototype('scalar')->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
```

Yet the config is not properly overwritten, making the test run fail.

What is going on here? I have succesfully rewritten other config entries using this strategy.

Comment: I wonder why you do the foreach and checks in AppKernel instead of use dependency injection extension.

Comment: @malcolm Easy answer: It's legacy ^^ So I can't name a reason why it has been done like that. Can you please point to an example of what you mean?

Comment: I mean the extension class in dependency injection in own bundle, if you do `processConfiguration` in `load` method, you have your bundle configuration dependent of actual environment. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html#processing-the-configs-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing `default_airports` in the files for each environment:

- `app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php`
- `app/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php`

the array lost its key, instead of the expected

```
`de` => arrray(0 => 'HAM')
```

there was a 0-indexed array.

So the relevant part of the `ConfigTreeBuilder` in the `Configuration.php` has to look like:

```
->arrayNode('default_airports')
   ->isRequired()
   ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
    ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
    ->prototype('array')
        ->useAttributeAsKey('name') // FIXES LOST KEY IN CONFIG FOR TEST ENV
        ->prototype('array')
            ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
            ->prototype('scalar')->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end()
```